# How to deserialize Xml with root than multiple child elements of the same type

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I'm trying deserialize a xml document that looks like this

```
<invoices>
  <invoice>2848</invoice>
  <invoice>2849</invoice>
  <invoice>2850</invoice>
  <invoice>2851</invoice>
  <invoice>2852</invoice>
</invoices>
```

Into a C# object, but I cannot get it to work. I'm using the `DataContractSerializer`

This is what my class looks like:

```
[DataContract(Name = "invoices", Namespace = "")]
public class Invoices
{
    [DataMember(Name = "invoice")]
    public Invoice[] InvoiceIds { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "invoice", Namespace = "")]
public class Invoice
{
    [DataMember(Name = "invoice")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Of course this does not work. I get this error:

```
{"Error in line 1 position 24. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. "}
```

I'm not in control of the Xml.

Comment: I am not up on `DataContractSerializer`, but to Serialize any normal class, it has to be marked as `Serializable()`. Does the `DataContract()` do this?

Comment: @jp2code, the `DataContractSerializer` doesn't need the `[Serializable]` attribute. It can serialize types marked with it, and also with others (`DataContract`, `CollectionDataContract`, `IXmlSerializable`, and even types not marked with anything, for which it uses some conventions about what to serialize).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a `[CollectionDataContract]` for this scenario:

```
public class StackOverflow_10705733
{
    [CollectionDataContract(Name = "invoices", ItemName = "invoice", Namespace = "")]
    public class Invoices : List<int>
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "invoice")]
        public int[] InvoiceIds { get; set; }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Invoices));
        string xml = @"<invoices>
                          <invoice>2848</invoice>
                          <invoice>2849</invoice>
                          <invoice>2850</invoice>
                          <invoice>2851</invoice>
                          <invoice>2852</invoice>
                        </invoices>";
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml));
        Invoices value = dcs.ReadObject(ms) as Invoices;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", value));
    }
}
```